# Ambiguous mobile screen resolution

Tags: html, css, mobile, screen-resolution

What is my phone real resolution? The resolution that CSS detects.

The phone is a Samsung S6. Its factory specifications show a resolution of 1440px x 2560px.

How ever when I use css `@media(max-width:...px)` to detect the screen resolution, the mobile browser acts as if it's somewhere between 768px and 991px width.

Using Google chrome inspection tool and toggling to mobile view, it shows that a Samsung S5 has a resolution of 360px x 640px.

So where is the real resolution in all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen size and screen resolution are NOT the same. You seem to be confusing the two.

Google's web developer tools detect the screen size (as in the width of the screen) as opposed to the screen resolution.

**Screen resolution** refers to the clarity of the text and images displayed on your screen.

At higher resolutions, such as 1600 x 1200 pixels, items appear sharper.

To summarise; the google inspection tool picks up the physical screen size of devices and emulates them, it does not emulate the screen resolution which is essentially the quality of the output of text/images.

Comment: ok I get the difference now.
But how come Google Chrome shows in the web developer tool "Galaxy S5 360 x 640" ?
It should be "Galaxy S5 980 X 1744" instead.

Comment: It is referring to the width of the device as in the width of the screen in pixels not the resolution. This is for CSS purposes. I don't understand the fixation on this topic. Take a look at [this] (http://mydevice.io/devices/) link it may help >

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems to be incorrect.

@OP here's what you need to know:

**Screen size** is the physical size of the screen, and is measured in inches.

**Screen resolution** is the number of pixels making up the screen, and is measured in pixels.

Your phone has a **resolution** of 1440x2560, as stated in the spec sheet.

So why does CSS act like the resolution is lower? It's because the contents of the screen that you are seeing on your mobile device are **zoomed in**.

This is done because showing text etc. at 100% size on a 1440x2560 display that is only ~6 inches would make the text so tiny as to be illegible.

So, if the amount of zoom is 200%, CSS thinks the screen is 720x1280. If 400% (as seems to be the case with your phone), CSS thinks 360x640. And so on...